# Shortcut key in visual studio to view file header context menu

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut key in visual studio 2017/19 to open the context menu on the file header?

If not, what would be the command so I may assign a shortcut key to it?

[image]

Note, Shift + F10 or the [Application Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)(aka menu key) would always provide me with the context menu on the file editor area.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to open current tab context menu

[image]

[image]