# Shortcut key in visual studio Code to view file header context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut key in visual studio code to open the context menu on the file header?

In Visual Studio 2017/19 its Alt + - as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924996/1977871).

I want to know for Visual Studio Code.

[image: Visual Studio Code file header context menu]