# Shortcut key in visual studio code to view the current editor tab's handle's context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-keybinding

Is there a shortcut in visual studio code to open the context menu of the currently open tab's handle? I want to open this menu via shortcut, not by right clicking on it with my mouse.

Here is the example:

[tab menu example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd6Sk.png)

There is a shortcut for this in visual studio <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> which i've found here: [visual studio post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56924832/shortcut-key-in-visual-studio-to-view-file-header-context-menu)

Comment: these commands are also in the `Ctrl+Shift+P` menu

Comment: Search for "context menu" in the Keyboard SHortcuts page.

Comment: Thanks @rioV8, that seems to be the best workaround so far! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a bindable command for opening the the context menu for editor tab handles at the time of this writing. Searching "context menu" in the keyboard shortcut editor, there are `editor.action.showContextMenu` (for the editor area), and `settings.action.showContextMenu` (for the settings UI), but that it.

Googling "`github vscode issues keyboard shortcut tab context menu`", I found the following:

- [Show context menu on a tab should be a command #93497](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93497)
- [List and tabs area: show context menu should be a command #93677](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93677)

Both are closed as backlog candidates. Maybe some day they will be looked at again.

I'm not aware of any workarounds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it seems like using the `Ctrl+Shift+P` menu is the best option right now, but i hope they will this add this option later, as they did in Visual Studio.

Comment: @michalnosiadek what command are you using in [the command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)?

Comment: I'm just typing `>close others` or `>split right` depending on what I need but yeah, I think it's better practice to just bind shortcuts to these commands. I'm just used to using `ctrl` + `-` from visual studio.